# Can I work out the variance based on a covariance matrix?

Tags: probability, covariance

Say I have a multivariate normal $Y_n$. Each Y have mean zero and they have a covariance matrix $\Omega$. And I am just wondering is there any way to work out a theoretical variance of $Y_n$? Intuitively this makes sense to me because as long as we have a covariance matrix and mean, we have all the information about this multi-distribution. But I have no idea how to do it...

Comment: The diagonal of the covariance matrix contains the variances. If you have the covariance matrix *without* the diagonal, the distribution is not determined (just consider the case where the covariance matrix only has zeroes off the diagonal).

Comment: But can I work out the overall variance among Yn?

Comment: I don't don't know what "overall variance" is.